# update mysql table with random value from another query?

Tags: php, mysql

im having a problem regrading a query which will update earning table with another random value from users table.
when executing the query it do nothing

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE earnings SET userid = (SELECT ID FROM users WHERE installid is NULL ORDER BY rand()) WHERE userid='0'");
```

in the second query

```
SELECT ID FROM users WHERE installid is NULL ORDER BY rand()
```

it will get me a random userid where installid null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried that query in phpMyAdmin etc? Are you getting an error?

Have you tried:

```
SELECT ID FROM users WHERE installid is NULL ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

So that the full query becomes:

```
UPDATE earnings SET userid = (SELECT ID FROM users WHERE installid is NULL ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) WHERE userid='0'
```

However keep in mind that you may end up having duplicate userid values in the earnings table.

Comment: i didn't try it using phpMyAdmin but your solution just work like charm thank you

Comment: @Fouad good to know it works. Please keep in mind that PHP will not show you any errors within your update query. You have explicitly handle the case when the query fails like by adding `or die(mysql_error())` after the call to `mysql_query()`

Comment: what if want edit this query to have WHERE userid= the Filed ID which located in the users table ?

Comment: sorry i meant  (SELECT ID FROM users WHERE installid is NULL AND ID=userid ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1)
userid is another filed within the earning table

Comment: @Fouad i am not sure if i understand what you want correctly it is probably best that you start a new question and put some details in there as to what exactly you are trying to do now.

Comment: @Fouad try `AND ID=earnings.userid`